# unable to perform mongodb oplog recovery

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I've taken a oplog backup after the timestamp `1683598975` using below mongodump command on node `server`.

```
mongodump -u username -p password --host=server --port=8303 -d local -c oplog.rs --oplog --authenticationDatabase=admin --ssl --query '{"ts": {"$gt": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1683598975, "i": 0}}}}' --out /tmp
```

This command has given 2 files;

> oplog.rs.bson

> oplog.rs.metadata.json

I would like to apply this oplog using mongorestore and oplog replay on node `server1` and I'm unable to do so.

I'm unable to restore from either of the files and tried to rename `oplog.rs.bson` to `oplog.bson` and tried to restore but getting below error:

```
mongorestore -u user -p password --host=server1 --port=8470 --authenticationDatabase=admin --ssl --oplogReplay /tmp/local/ -vvvv
2023-05-09T11:29:40.885+0000    using write concern: &{majority false 0}
2023-05-09T11:29:40.926+0000    checking options
2023-05-09T11:29:40.926+0000            dumping with object check disabled
2023-05-09T11:29:40.926+0000    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2023-05-09T11:29:40.926+0000    connected to node type: replset
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    mongorestore target is a directory, not a file
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    preparing collections to restore from
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    using /tmp/local as dump root directory
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    found oplog.bson file to replay
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    enqueued collection '.oplog'
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    finalizing intent manager with longest task first prioritizer
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    restoring up to 4 collections in parallel
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    starting restore routine with id=3
2023-05-09T11:29:40.927+0000    ending restore routine with id=3, no more work to do
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    starting restore routine with id=2
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    ending restore routine with id=2, no more work to do
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    starting restore routine with id=1
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    ending restore routine with id=1, no more work to do
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    starting restore routine with id=0
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    ending restore routine with id=0, no more work to do
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    replaying oplog
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    skipping applying the config.system.sessions namespace in applyOps
2023-05-09T11:29:40.928+0000    skipping applying the config.system.sessions namespace in applyOps
2023-05-09T11:29:40.936+0000    skipping applying the config.system.sessions namespace in applyOps
2023-05-09T11:29:40.936+0000    skipping applying the config.system.sessions namespace in applyOps
2023-05-09T11:29:40.936+0000    skipping applying the config.system.sessions namespace in applyOps
2023-05-09T11:29:41.781+0000    Failed: restore error: error applying oplog: applyOps: (DuplicateKey) E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.system.users index: user_1_db_1 dup key: { user: null, db: null }
2023-05-09T11:29:41.781+0000    0 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```